# Linux .sh file with grep

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to edit an existing Linux .sh script that uses grep. I need to remove or comment out some lines that use the -e command line option. When I delete or comment out a line, I get error command not found on the line before the one deleted or commented out. To comment out I just put # in front of line. If I delete it, I am not touching any of the surrounding lines. Why would I be getting a command not found error?
Thanks
Lele

Code below: for example, I want to remove the line that searches for child.

```
rga -S --binary --rga-adapters=+pdfpages,tesseract -M=250 --max 
columns-preview --max-count 20 --heading -H -w -P e'accommodation'\ 
-e 'child(?!\<)(?!>)(?!=)' \
-e '[\w]+[\\@][a-z]{1,30}[\.][a-z]{3}' \
-e '[0-9]{3}[-|\s][0-9]{2}[-|\s][0-9]{4}' \
-e '[\\(]?[0-9]{3}[\\)]?[\s|\-]?[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{4}' \
-e '[0-9]{3}[\-|\s][0-9]{4}' \
```

Comment: You [just asked the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562208/linux-sh-file-grep-e) and it was closed. Fix that one instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: I tried but couldn't get the status to change from closed.

Comment: It doesn't happen automatically, you have to wait for 3 people to vote to reopen it.

Comment: You can't put a comment in the middle of a multi-line command. The comment ends the command.

Comment: You have to wait more than a few minutes to get reopen votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a comment in the middle of a command. So you have to remove the `child` line completely. If you want to keep track of what you removed, you can add that as a separate comment

```
rga -S --binary --rga-adapters=+pdfpages,tesseract -M=250 --max 
columns-preview --max-count 20 --heading -H -w -P e'accommodation'\ 
-e '[\w]+[\\@][a-z]{1,30}[\.][a-z]{3}' \
-e '[0-9]{3}[-|\s][0-9]{2}[-|\s][0-9]{4}' \
-e '[\\(]?[0-9]{3}[\\)]?[\s|\-]?[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{4}' \
-e '[0-9]{3}[\-|\s][0-9]{4}' \

# removed this:
# -e 'child(?!\<)(?!>)(?!=)' \
```

Comment: Thank You Barmar!  I had 4 lines to remove and was getting 4 errors. I deleted them as you said and am now getting one command not found error after removing the line under -e 'accommodation'\    My original post didn't have the - in front of the e but my script does.

Comment: Actually, I found extra spaces after -e 'accommodation'\. I deleted them and it works. Thank You again.

Comment: Are the backticks in the real script, or were they for SO markdown? You don't use backticks if you put the code in a code block. Also, you shouldn't have a backslash at the end of the last line.

Comment: That was for posting here. Sorry. The backslash was in the sample code here because there were several more lines that I didn't post.